# Intuition? how the author reaches the answer?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis, monomial-ideals

I've a question on 2 problems in [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=3PxzYIBTibsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=monomial+ideals&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_pw9U6qSB8LItQbLsIDQDQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=monomial%20ideals&f=false):

> 2.4. Let $S = K[x_1, . . . , x_6]$. Let $f = x_1x_5 − x_2x_4$, $g = x_1x_6 − x_3x_4$ and
>   $h = x_2x_6 − x_3x_5$.
>   (a) Find a monomial order $<$ on $S$ such that {$f, g, h$} is a Grobner basis of
>   $I = (f, g, h)$ with respect to $<$.
>
> 2.8. Let $S = K[x_1, x_2, . . . , x_8]$ and $I$ the ideal of $S$ generated by
>   $f_1 = x_2x_8 − x_4x_7, f_2 = x_1x_6 − x_3x_5, f_3 = x_1x_3 − x_2x_4$.
>   (a) Show that there exists no monomial order $<$ on $S$ such that ${f_1, f_2, f_3}$ is
>   a Grobner basis of $I$ with respect to $<$.

**I don't want a solution** but I wish to know how these examples made. How can I reach an answer? Example 2.1.10 has a solution to a similar problem, which I **can understand**, but I don't understand **how the author reaches the answer**.

Comment: thanks for your comment. it is not two different questions, it's 1. i don't want solutions. these two questions are relevant. and I'd like to know intuition: how one can reach for example the polynomials in solution of Example 2.1.10

Comment: If the title have been more informative then maybe the OP of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723417/find-a-monomial-order-on-s-kx-1-dots-x-6-such-that-f-g-h-is-a-g) would have found this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, the title should be modified to refer to the content.

In both questions, a monomial order will pick a monomial out of your polynomials. A priori there are $2^3$ possibilities, since you have three binomials.

The theorem to know is that when $I$ is fixed, we can restrict from arbitrary term orders to ones based on a weighting $\vec w$, where ${\bf x}^{\vec e} < {\bf x}^{\vec f} \iff \vec e \cdot \vec w < \vec f \cdot \vec w$. Now each statement like "$x_1x_5 < x_2 x_4$" becomes an inequality on $\vec w$. Finding a $\vec w$ satisfying a bunch of such conditions is now a linear programming problem.

Comment: Allen Knutson: thank you. i don't know terminology and can't understand what you wrote. please note a reference and explain more please.

Comment: Say $\vec w=(w_1,\ldots,w_8)$. Then declaring $x_2 x_4$ to be the initial term of $x_1 x_5 - x_2 x_4$, with respect to the $\vec w$ order, gives the linear inequality $w_2 + w_4 > w_1 + w_5$. In your first question, you need to decide which of the two terms in each binomial you want to be the leading term, in such a way that the resulting S-polynomials reduce to 0. But then you need to be sure that there is a term order that actually gives those choices of initial term. So find a $\vec w$ satisfying the three attendant linear inequalities.